# How can I show DTFT result in MATLAB?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, sampling, ifft, dtft

[image]

I wanna show DTFT result and convolution result in f-domain are same.

Additionally, I wanna show sampled function and inverse fourier transform result are same too.

How can I show this? If I use just FFT or DFT, they don't show picture-like.
If I have to use other function (e.g diric, freqz, etc), then please let me know how can I use, and input value mean.

Comment: The way you ask this, it's just a matlab programming, not a signal processing question (and hence, off-topic here). However, I think you have an underlying math unclarity: Are you expecting a numerical calculation to give you analytic results, or are you directly going for symbolic calculations (something for which there's matlab extensions, but not something that matlab is meant for)? In either way, this is really hardly a signal processing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTFT is continuous, so you have to approximate the DTFT on a computer.

Zero padding “interpolates” the DFT, so  a lot of zero padding will approximate the DTFT